# If $f'(x)>f(x)>0$ holds for all $x$ on $[0,1]$, prove that $\frac{f(1)}{f(0)}>e$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

If $f'(x)>f(x)>0$ holds for all $x$ on $[0,1]$, prove that $$\frac{f(1)}{f(0)}>e$$

I know that if $f'(x)=f(x)>0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, I can get $f(x)=Ce^x$ ($C>0$) and therefore $\frac{f(1)}{f(0)}=e$. And I can understand that as $f'(x)$ is greater, the $f(x)$ grows faster, so the result of $\frac{f(1)}{f(0)}$ should also be greater too. But I cannot get a well written prove to it.

Comment: MVT on $e^xf(x)$.

Comment: Another possibility that may help: $\frac{d}{dx}(\log f(x)) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$

Answer (score 0):

Can you prove that if $f(0) = g(0)$ and $f'(x) \geq g'(x)$ then $f(1) \geq g(1)$? The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus will be useful here:

$$f(1) - f(0) = \int_{0}^{1}f'(x) dx$$

Comment: Mean Value Theorem is the one I would reach for here

Comment: Yes, MVT is preferable, since you do not need to assume $f'$ is integrable.